# Certain non-latin characters are displaying out of order

Tags: html, css, fonts, character

EDIT: got it by some dedicated searching. `unicode-bidi: plaintext` on the font's `i` style block does it. Very nice to be able to scope it so tightly; hopefully this won't muck with localization like a broader solution might.

---

Kind of hard to explain, but I'm using a webfont that leverages unicode glyphs to display its own characters.

The following code is displaying the shield between the `0` and the `+`

```
<span class="text-stat ng-star-inserted" style="">
  <i class="game-icon game-icon-shield"></i>
  0+
</span>
```

But this code displays everything in the right order (Seemingly any a-zA-Z makes it work correctly)

```
<span class="text-stat ng-star-inserted" style="">
  <i class="game-icon game-icon-shield"></i>
  a0+
</span>
```

Looking at the CSS provided for the webfont, I see this:

```
.game-icon-shield:before {
    content: "ﱗ";
}
.game-icon:before {
    font-family: "game-icons" !important;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: inherit;
}
```

It seems like the character `ﱗ`intrinsically places itself after a subsequent zero, for some reason? `ﱗ0` typing that out, I placed the `ﱗ` before the zero but it moved itself over. `ﱗa0` works fine.
I'm trying to enforce code-order for this portion of my page but I don't see a way to do that with css. `direction: ltr` has no effect.

Comment: The unicode text in that CSS is the [ARABIC LIGATURE YEH WITH KHAH ISOLATED FORM](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/FC57/index.htm) codepoint, which _must_ use right-to-left typesetting because, as the name implies, it's Arabic. Whoever made that font should not have just picked a random codepoint, they should have used Private Use Area codepoints, which literally exist to prevent nonsense like this from happening, so... contact the font creator and have them fix their font =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans oh yes, I realize that. However, the font creator made an auto-generation script for the font and requests that updates be done in the form of PRs, so it'd be up to me to fix it and submit a pull request. Additionally, changing this would break things for all prior font users so there might be some friction. :)

Comment: Not really. They request that _updates_ be done as PR, but you're not updating the font: you're letting them know that their generator has a pretty bad bug that someone (either they, or someone else who knows how their font generator works) can address. Letting folks know their software has bugs does not mean the reported should be the one fixing those bugs too =) (As for breaking changes: that's what major versions are for)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermanswell, in this case, the maintainer always requests that PRs be made when bugs are reported.

Comment: Just tell them you have no idea how fonts work, or how their code generator works, and instead point them at this SO post that reveals a bad bug in their font. Maintainers are free to ask for PRs, but if you're just reporting a bug, it's perfectly fine to say "I have no idea how to, here's a link that details the problem, and here's the test case that reproduces the problem" with enough code for them to just run and see that, indeed, their font has a bug that they need to get fixed.